# Python - updating a set

Tags: python-3.x, set

I'm trying to update a set of nodes with their positions (coordinates) using Python.

```
n = 5  #number of current nodes
vertices = []
vertices=list(range(n)) # list of vertices=[0,1,2,3,4]
```

I'm creating a random set of points as follows for each element in vertices:

```
pos = {i:(random.randint(0,50),random.randint(0,50)) for i in vertices}
```

Also, I have another list(called "`s`") with some coordinates and I'm enumerating those elements in "`s`" to add an index(to continue with indices in "`vertices`") to each coordinate in "`s`".

```
for index, i in enumerate(s , vertices[-1]+1):
    print(index, i)
```

Then, I'm getting my output as

```
5 (29.5, 34.0)
6 (20.0, 25.75)
7 (23.75, 36.0)
```

Now I need to update my set "`pos`" with these points and their corresponding indices. How can I do that?

Comment: You're talking a lot about a set, but you're using a dict, and you *should* be using a list here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign like this while iterating itself instead of just printing

```
for index, i in enumerate(s, vertices[-1] + 1):
    pos[index] = i
```

And finally, the `pos` will be something like

```
{0: (0, 10), 1: (16, 33), 2: (17, 36), 3: (40, 13), 4: (26, 39), 5: (29.5, 34.0), 6: (20.0, 25.75), 7: (23.75, 36.0)}
```

Comment: Hi itsneo, thank you very much for your answer.. :) That works fine!